# Create Azure AD "New client secret" with cli

Tags: azure-devops

How can I create a Azure AD client secret with the cli the following command seems to delete the already existing "client secret".

```
az ad sp credential reset --name {name}  --end-date 2025-03-04 --credential-description {credential-name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use AZ rest in the bash shell

```
az rest --method POST   --headers "Content-Type=application/json"   --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications/{id}/addPassword'  --body '{"passwordCredential":{"displayName":"test","endDateTime":"2032-05-11T07:29:41.763Z","startDateTime":"2021-11-11T08:29:41.763Z"}}'
```